# Java Math.min Math.max Errors

Tags: java, user-input

My goal is to have the java program receive input from a user, display the inputted number, between 1 and 5. So if a user enters a number greater than 5, it shows as 5, and if the number is lower than 1, it shows as 1. However the program is only showing an output of 1 regardless of the number entered.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMax {

        int minNum = 1;
        int maxNum = 5;

        public int inputNum() {
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            int userinput = Integer.parseInt(userInput.nextLine());
            return (userinput);
        } 

        public void displayNum(int userNum) {
            userNum = 0;
            Math.min(userNum, minNum);
            Math.max(userNum, maxNum);
            System.out.printf("%d\n", Math.min(1, 
            Math.max(5, userNum)));
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {    
            TestMax TestMax = new TestMax();
            int userNum = TestMax.inputNum();
            TestMax.displayNum(userNum);
        }

}
```

Comment: related [Having trouble with java.lang.Math(i get an error stating I'm using an Int and it needs a String)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60178886/85421) ?

Comment: Your expressions with just `Math.min` and `Math.max`, not operated on or assigned, have no net effect. `Math.min(userNum, minNum);` just calculates a result and throws it away unless you do something with that result.

Answer (score 4):

`Math.min(1, n)` will always return `1` if `n >= 1` and `Math.max(5, n)` will always return `5` if `n <= 5`. You need to swap them:

```
System.out.printf("%d\n", Math.max(1, Math.min(5, userNum)));
```