# Having trouble with java.lang.Math(i get an error stating I'm using an Int and it needs a String)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.lang.Math;

public class TestMax {

    int minNum = 1, maxNum = 5;

    public int inputNum() {
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        return inputNum();

    }

    public void displayNum(int userNum) {
        System.out.printf(Math.min(userNum, maxNum));
        System.out.printf(Math.max(userNum, minNum));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMax input;
        input = new TestMax();
        int userNum = input.inputNum();
        input.displayNum(userNum);

    }


}
```

Sorry about any incorrect formatting, it's my first time posting.  I'm creating a program for a school in which a user enters a number and the program then outputs the 'maxNum' or 'minNum' depending on whether the number entered is less than or greater than the min/maxNum.  I think I have everything right except for when it comes to the math function.  I want it to compare the userNum to the min/maxNum but its saying I'm using an int and need a string.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `printf` requires a format `String` as first argument, it's `print` or `println` that takes any object (or primitive), including an `int` to print (be warned that `return inputNum();` inside `inputNum` will end up calling itself until the stack overflows = endless recursive call)

Comment: related [Java Math.min Math.max Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60178792/85421) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a number from Scanner like this:

```
 public int inputNum() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = s.nextInt();
        return number;
    }
```

Comment: A `Scanner` is not an `int` or a `String`.  You're looking for [`Scanner::nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()).

Comment: okay, I've changed that but what I'm really having trouble with is in the next block where it wont allow me to use 'userNum' in the Math.max function.

Comment: @ColinAsh is can you please show me the error you are getting?

Comment: @manzk another user posted a link to someone asking the same question and I've figured it out, thanks for all your help